# How to scale to a specific point/distance

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, coordinates

I have a shape I need to scale but I need the back of it to be exactly at 1.5y. Is there any way to do this or will I be stuck working out the math? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Try using proportional editing and 3D cursor as pivot point while scaling the front edge.

Comment: That almost works perfectly except how do I increase the range of edges it affects? right now it only affects a few.

Comment: When you scale, scroll the middle mouse button to increase or decrease the influence.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain geometry from that?

Comment: I think you mean limit the scale on specific axis? why do you want to hide some of the geometry?

Comment: I figured it out. I wanted to scale the whole wing area but not the X's. I just hid them and they were unaffected.

Comment: Shift+X will exclude X axis while scaling.

Comment: I meant the X's on the model not the axis

Comment: Then switch proportional editing to **Connected**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Select the edge that you want the model scaled from and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select from menu **Cursor to Selected**.
2. Change Pivot Point to 3D Cursor and enable **Proportional Editing**.
3. Scale the edge and scroll the middle mouse button to increase or decrease the influence of proportional editing.

To to scale only on one axis hit <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> buttons while scaling, or to exclude one axis use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer, but a good add-on:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?335568-Addon-Directly-Set-Length%28edge%29-and-Angle%28edges%29-v0-2

Comment: I don't think that works for what I need.